# How to use .join() with Thread at this particular Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, synchronized

My application is making some heavy Algorithm calculation at a very high speed . Each time the orientation sensor is changed it activates the Algorithm if it's not already running. 
The algorithm is `Threaded` because I want to keep using my application `Buttons` and `Exit` button no matter if Algorithm is running or not. If I call Algorithm `method` on `trackingActivity` the Algorithm is being activated but I can't use any `button` on my app screen. Threading is useful at this case especially because I need to display the Algorithm outcome on application main screen. That is why I need to use `Threading`- to make Algorithm as a parallel process. 
My main propose of using `.join()` is because I do not want a sensor changed interrupt to activate my Algorithm as long as current Algorithm execution is already running.

That's is my code & `Thread`:

```
 package com.application.i;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class trackingActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    TextView Xlocation;
    TextView Ylocation;
    TextView Zlocation;
    TextView Iterations;
    TextView Pit;
    TextView pitch;
    TextView roll;
    TextView yaw;
    private double azimuth_angle;
    private double roll_angle;
    private double pitch_angle;
    float[] orientations;

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mOrientation;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.trackingsub);

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mOrientation,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        super.onResume();
        trackingActivity t = new trackingActivity();

        double[] Locations = t.Algo(pitch_angle, roll_angle, azimuth_angle);
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        azimuth_angle = event.values[0];
        pitch_angle = event.values[1];
        roll_angle = event.values[2];
        // Do something with these orientation angles.
        double[] orientations = { pitch_angle, roll_angle, azimuth_angle };

        // mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        pitch = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pitcher);
        roll = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.roller);
        yaw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yawer);
        String p = String.valueOf(pitch_angle);
        String r = String.valueOf(roll_angle);
        String a = String.valueOf(azimuth_angle);
        pitch.setText(p);
        roll.setText(r);
        yaw.setText(a);



    while(true){
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                     public void run()
                           {


                              try 
                               {
                        synchronized (this) { 
                             X = 10.6569;
                             Y = 20.3265;
                             Z = 30.259;

                                locations = algo(X,Y,Z,pitch_angle, roll_angle,
                                            azimuth_angle);

                             }

                               } 
                               catch (Exception e) 
                               {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } 




                           }
                            }).start();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

I noticed that `algo` method is executed with no order, I mean that this `Thread` do not wait for its previous action and starts new `Thread`.

By searching online I found `.join()`, `.join()` force a `Thread` to wait until it's being finished and only then start again at this case.

My question is :
How to force this `Thread` to start only after it finishes with its previous activation? 
Or , how to implement this `.join()` here?

Solution:

```
 while(true){
      Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                     public void run()
                           {


                              try 
                               {
                        synchronized (this) { 
                             X = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex]);
                             Y = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex+1]);
                             Z = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex+2]);
                             textIndex+=3;
                                locations = algo(X,Y,Z,pitch_angle, roll_angle,
                                            azimuth_angle);

                             }

                               } 
                               catch (Exception e) 
                               {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } 




                           }
                            });
t.start();

t.join();  \\ auto-correction my force you to use try-catch

}
```

Comment: Seems you are missing some basics... What's the purpose of your loop creating new threads on each entry, if you always want to wait for the former one to finish?! You don't seem to need those threads, because you are simply not doing anything parallel. Additionally, synchronizing on "this", which is your created thread, doesn't make sense as well.

Comment: You are right, I'm missing basics, that's why I ask. This algorithm is activated every time a onSensorChanged is being called. That's why I need to activate it and only when finish to activate it again, the thread is because this algorithm is super heavy and Threading make my app run faster.

Comment: By the way: next time spent a bit more time on formatting your code. You expect other people to help you; so don't make their job **harder** by throwing such badly formatted code at them.

Comment: @Hadar.S In your example threading doesn't change anything, because you are waiting on the end of the thread within a never ending loop. There is nothing running in parallel. Your app will only benefit of threading if things run in parallel, if you have enoguh CPU cores to run things in parallel and so on...

Comment: Hi, every time that Algo finish it sends 3 values to a text file, this values were aligned with no correlation to the first second and third values that Algo is getting. instead it was with correlation to second third first values. If you say that nothing is running in parallel what caused that? as I used .join() the values were aligned right.

Comment: I rewrite this Question because I still got a Question ban, please Vote up if you think that's OK. I got this ban for 2 months now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you've created a class for your Thread like

`Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable(...));
 myThread.start();`

you can wait for this thread to finish by adding the line `myThread.join()` as last line of yout while loop.

This will cause the main-thread to wait for myThread to finish before it continues.

So your code would look as follows:

```
    while(true){
        Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                 public void run()
                       {


                          try 
                           {
                    synchronized (this) { 
                         X = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex]);
                         Y = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex+1]);
                         Z = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex+2]);
                         textIndex+=3;
                            locations = algo(X,Y,Z,pitch_angle, roll_angle,
                                        azimuth_angle);

                         }

                           } 
                           catch (Exception e) 
                           {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } 
                       }
                        });
myThread.start();
myThread.join();
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! That is the correct way! . My mistake was leaving }).start(); at the end of the Thread so it immediately marked all Thread lines as errors. just a little change, Eclipse forced me to use try,catch on .join().

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call method `algo()` sequentially in a thread:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    X = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex]);
                    Y = (double) Float
                            .parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex + 1]);
                    Z = (double) Float
                            .parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex + 2]);
                    textIndex += 3;
                    locations = algo(X, Y, Z, pitch_angle, roll_angle,
                            azimuth_angle);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in that way the algo won't start again?? as I can tell java is asynchronous and this will activate algo and do the while loop again.

Comment: Of course it will run algo again, but it does so in your original answer and it does so if you wait for the end of the thread. The difference is only WHEN algo will run again, not IF. Java is not asnyc BTW.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
    Thread toExec = new Thread(new Runnable() {

             public void run()
                   {


                      try 
                       {
                synchronized (this) { 
                     X = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex]);
                     Y = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex+1]);
                     Z = (double) Float.parseFloat(Splited2[textIndex+2]);
                     textIndex+=3;
                        locations = algo(X,Y,Z,pitch_angle, roll_angle,
                                    azimuth_angle);

                     }

                       } 
                       catch (Exception e) 
                       {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } 




                   }
                    }).start();
                toExec.join();
}
```

Comment: No explanations whatsoever; and you just copied the extremely poorly formatted code fragment ... do you really think this will help to answer that question; he might even be missing that you added that one line there. And then, the program is obviously still "wrong"; as there is absolutely no sense in having that while loop there.

Comment: Just look the answer below you.